# Error getting access to LLVM Debian/Ubuntu nightly packages

Tags: apt, ppa

Trying to access [LLVM Debian/Ubuntu nightly packages](http://apt.llvm.org/)

I am on 14.04 and they give this info:

> The goal is to provide Debian and Ubuntu nightly packages ready to be
>   installed with minimal impact on the distribution. Packages are
>   available for amd64 and i386 and for both the stable, qualification
>   and development branches (currently 3.9, 4.0 and 5.0).
>
> The packages provide LLVM + Clang + compiler-rt + polly + LLDB + LLD +
>   libFuzzer

```
Trusty (14.04) - Last update : Wed, 22 Mar 2017 08:38:03 UTC / Revision: 298477

deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty main
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty main
# 3.9 
deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.9 main
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.9 main
# 4.0 
deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-4.0 main
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-4.0 main
```

I have tried going in Ubuntu Software Centre and adding the deb line for both 3.9 and 4.0. 
But after `sudo apt-get update` I get an error:

```
W: GPG error: http://apt.llvm.org llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.9 InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 15CF4D18AF4F7421
```

There is some way to install this without Ubuntu Software Centre, but I don't know how to find the ppa:user/ppa-name as talked about [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was getting the same error. I fixed it by installing [launchpad-getkeys](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/automatically-import-all-missing.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install launchpad-getkeys
```

Once it's installed, run:

```
sudo launchpad-getkeys
sudo apt-get update
```

Your key errors should be gone.

Comment: Third step yields "Unable to locate package launchpad-getkeys" on my system

Comment: Thanks, worked! Fixed my LLVM absent GPG keys.

Answer (score 11):

Each one of these repositories has it's own key which you should add before updating your lists. See https://apt.llvm.org/

E.g: if you add this one to your sources:

```
deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty main
```

Then you should also add the related key to this component, which is:

```
wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -
```

So, if you add all lines for trusty, then you should add all three related keys to them, It will make your error goes away.

---

For stable brunch (V3), source:

```
 deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.9 main

 wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -
```

For qualification branch (V4), source:

```
deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-4.0 main

wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: why is there no difference in the URL for llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.9 and llvm-toolchain-trusty-4.0? Is that intended?

Comment: They're different, the first one is a reference to this link https://apt.llvm.org/trusty/dists/llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.9/ and the second one is this one: https://apt.llvm.org/trusty/dists/llvm-toolchain-trusty-4.0/

Comment: The URL for wget is always https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key is always the same. But that is obviously intended as for all LLVM packages the same key pair is used. (I checked it on 18.04 with clang-format-13 of llvm-toolchain-bionic-13.)