# How to use a more recent clang-format or clang-tidy version on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04

Meanwhile [LLVM has released apt packages](https://apt.llvm.org/) for LLVM 13 and 14 but out-of-the box clang-format-13, clang-tidy-13, ... are not available via `apt-get install clang-format-13`.

How can I install clang-format-13 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all do a `sudo apt update` and an optional `sudo apt upgrade` and check everything is fine and works.
Second backup the sources.list you want to update (next).

Add the matching repository from https://apt.llvm.org/ to one of your sources, e.g. `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Example:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic main'
```

That should add the following to the end of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-13 main
# deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-13 main
```

Then execute `sudo apt update`. In case you get an error stating 'The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ...' then you have to [add the missing public key with `apt-key add`](https://askubuntu.com/a/906366/1595591):

```
# download key file
wget https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key
# add the key
sudo apt-key add llvm-snapshot.gpg.key
```

One liner: `wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -`. Please notice that you now trust the packages with that key!

Then you can install clang-format-13, clang-tidy-13 on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install clang-format-13
```

This should also work for Ubuntu 20.04 (`http://apt.llvm.org/focal/` and `llvm-toolchain-focal-13`) or clang-format-14.

Comment: For clang-format-12 [see this SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66654073/3054219)

Comment: After following the accepted answer, I can only install clang-format-12. clang-format-13 and clang-format-14 still report "Unable to locate package"

Comment: Someone (nobody here) needs to give their head a wobble and make this process easier.

Comment: Says that `apt-key is deprecated` in 22.04.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issues for install `clang-format-12` on Ubuntu 18.04 I solved mine by running the script below

```
wget https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh
chmod +x llvm.sh
sudo ./llvm.sh 12
sudo apt install clang-format-12
```

for clang-format-13 I believe replacing the 12 with 13 like below would solve it

```
wget https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh
chmod +x llvm.sh
sudo ./llvm.sh 13
sudo apt install clang-format-13
```

Comment: Works for clang-format-18 as well.

Comment: Also works for clang-format-18 as well to me.